# POST JSON to Node.JS , SyntaxError: Unexpected token %

Tags: javascript, android, json, node.js, mongodb

I want to POST JSON object to Mongodb by Node.JS  POST API ,can not upload anything than node.js always print  ,

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token %

if I remove the android side :

> Connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

It can upload to DB but became an undefined

> {"{\"artist\":\"U\",\"weeksAtOne\":\"000000\",\"decade\":\"Hhhhh\",......

This is the android JSON Object looks like in debug mode

> jsonObject = {JSONObject@18572}
>   "{"artist":"Fffffff","weeksAtOne":"Ppp","decade":"Kkkkk","song":"888","__v":0}"

it doesn't have token "%", but node.js always print this , Please help , stuck here for all day

android code

```
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                jsonObject.put("artist", artist.getText().toString());
                jsonObject.put("weeksAtOne", week.getText().toString());
                jsonObject.put("decade", year.getText().toString());
                jsonObject.put("song", song.getText().toString());
                jsonObject.put("__v",0);

                String http = "http://36.224.137.68:3000/songs";
                URL url = new URL(http);
                Connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                Connection.setDoOutput(true);
                Connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                Connection.setUseCaches(false);
                Connection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
                Connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
                Connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                Connection.setRequestProperty("Host", "36.224.137.68:3000/songs");
                Connection.connect();
                OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(Connection.getOutputStream());
                out.write(jsonObject.toString());
                out.write(URLEncoder.encode(jsonObject.toString(), "UTF-8"));
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                int HttpResult = 0;
                try {
                HttpResult = Connection.getResponseCode();
                }catch (IOException ioex){
                    Log.v("ConnError", ioex.getMessage());
                };
                if (HttpResult == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                            Connection.getInputStream(), "utf-8"));
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    br.close();

                    System.out.println("" + sb.toString());

                } else {
                    System.out.println(Connection.getResponseMessage());
                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                if(Connection!=null)
                    Connection.disconnect();
            }


        }
    });

}
}
```

NodeJS : app.js code

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // support encoded bodies
songs = require('./routes/route');
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();


app.post('/songs', function(req, res) {
console.log("Request.Body : " + JSON.stringify(req.body));
if (!req.body) return res.sendStatus(400);
songs.addSong(req, res);
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});


app.get('/songs',songs.findAll);
app.get('/findById/:id',songs.findById);
app.post('/songs',songs.addSong);
```

route.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var uri =         "mongodb://xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx@ds061365.mongolab.com:61365/aweitest";
mongoose.connect(uri);
// we're connected!
var db = mongoose.connection.db;
var BSON = require('bson').BSONPure;

var body = require('body-parser');

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection errrrrrrrror:'));
//db = mongoose.connection.db;
db.once('open', function() {
console.log("mongodb is connected!!");
});

exports.findAll = function(req, res) {
db.collection('songs',function(err, collection) {
collection.find().toArray(function(err, items) {
  res.send(items);
});
});
};

exports.findById = function(req, res) {
var id = req.params.id;
console.log('Retrieving song: ' + id);
db.collection('songs', function(err, collection)
{ if (err) {
throw err;
} else
collection.findOne({'_id':new BSON.ObjectID(id)}, function(err, item) {
  res.send(item);
});
});
};

exports.addSong = function(req, res) {
var song = req.body;
console.log('Adding song: ' + JSON.stringify(song));
db.collection('songs', function(err, collection) {
collection.insert(song, {safe:true}, function(err, result) {
  if (err) {
    res.send({'error':'An error has occurred'});
  } else {
    console.log('Success: ' + JSON.stringify(result[0]));
    res.send(result[0]);
  }
});
});
}
```

Comment: You output the JSON string twice, the second time with `out.write(URLEncoder.encode(jsonObject.toString(), "UTF-8"));`. The line preceding it, seems to do what needs to be done, so remove this one. URLEncoding data that is posted makes no sense and can indeed introduce `%` characters.

Comment: ! you are right! THANK YOU! can you answer , than I can vote you!! 10000THANKS!

Comment: Done and you're welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You output the JSON string twice in these two lines:

```
out.write(jsonObject.toString());
out.write(URLEncoder.encode(jsonObject.toString(), "UTF-8"));
```

The first line seems to do what needs to be done perfectly, so remove the second one.

While such duplication in itself already results in invalid JSON, URL encoding data that is posted makes no sense either, and can indeed introduce the `%` characters you are confronted with.